# jQuery animate height and overflow

Tags: jquery, css

I am using CSS and jQuery. I have a jQuery click event that toggles a class. When the element is not toggled the height is 0 and overflow is hidden, when I toggle the class the height is still 0 but the overflow is visible. My question is how do I animate this? I am looking for away to slide down the content in overflow hidden element.

CSS

```
.section1, .section2, .section3, .section4, .section5, .section6, .section7 {
     overflow: hidden;
     height: 0px;
}

.toggle {
     overflow: visible;
}
```

jQuery

```
   $('.architectural-films').bind('click', function(e){

       $(".section1").toggleClass("toggle").promise().done(function(){ 


           $(window).trigger('resize.px.parallax');

       });

       return false;
    });
```

**UPDATE**

I have tried the following:

```
.section1, .section2, .section3, .section4, .section5, .section6, .section7 {
     overflow: hidden;
     transform: scaleY(0);
     transform-origin: top;
     transition: transform 0.15s ease-out;
     max-height: 0px;
}

.toggle {
     overflow: visible;
     transform: scaleY(1);
     transition: transform 0.15s ease-in;
}
```

The problem is when removing the toggle class the transition does not happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `max-height` property, but you have to set it to some **fixed** value:

```
.section1, .section2, .section3, .section4, .section5, .section6, .section7 {
     overflow: hidden;
     max-height: 0px;
     transition: max-height 0.15s ease-out;
}

.toggle {
     overflow: visible;
     max-height: 200px;
}
```

If you want **automatic** height you can use `transform` property:

```
.section1, .section2, .section3, .section4, .section5, .section6, .section7 {
     overflow: hidden;
     transform: scaleY(0);
     transform-origin: top;
     transition: transform 0.15s ease-out;
}

.toggle {
     overflow: visible;
     transform: scaleY(1);
}
```

Comment: Trying this now.

Comment: I updated my question, this works well, but does not transition when removing the class toggle.

Comment: Also, when using transform, the content in the .section is appears squished as its transitioning.

Comment: I just tried the max-height idea, when removing the toggle class everything looks weird. http://new.sekanskin.com/what-we-do/